# Can we slice an object into two pieces similar to the original?

Tags: geometry

I suspect it is impossible to split a (any) 3d solid into two, such that each of the pieces is identical in shape (but not volume) to the original.  How can I prove this?

Comment: On a related note: Kimmo Eriksson proves in 
[The American Mathematical Monthly
Vol. 103, No. 5 (May, 1996), pp. 393-400] that a convex polygon is splittable in two properly congruent pieces iff it has rotational symmetry.

Comment: A couple of questions. 1) What exactly does split mean? 2) Why is this tagged topology?

Comment: Is this connected to [the Banach-Tarski paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach-Tarski)?

Comment: Was thinking of a 3d analogue to Pythagoras' Theorem.

Comment: Isaac, I don't think so, because that paradox involves dividing a sphere into non-spherical pieces.  But I am also curious if there are any solutions involving pathological shapes or division methods.

Answer (score 9):

You can certainly take a rectangular box, $2^{1/3} \times 2^{2/3} \times 2$ and slice it into two boxes of size $1 \times 2^{1/3} \times 2^{2/3}$.

Comment: I'm confused, doesn't this contradict the theorem in the answer Mariano Suárez-Alvarez wrote?

Comment: Not impossible then.

Comment: @muad: Boxes aren't strictly convex.

Comment: @whuber, thank you - I understand now

Comment: Also can we make the pieces different sizes and connect them sideways, like a Golden Rectangle?  How many different ways are there to do this in n-space?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that Puppe and others proved that this is impossible for *any* strictly convex solid. See [B. L van den Waerden, Aufgabe Nr 51, *Elem. Math.* **4** (1949) **18**, 140]

The reference comes from *Unsolved problems in geometry* by Hallard T. Croft, K. J. Falconer and Richard K. Guy.

Comment: Is it also true that no strictly convex solid can be divided into _any_ two strictly convex pieces, whether or not they are identical with each other or either with the original?

Comment: @Dab, I would imagine that that is true (for at a point where the two pieces touch which is not at the boundary of the original body at most one of them will be strictly convex)